# Why does Fock operator in Hartree-Fock method have the molecule symmetry?

Tags: many-body, quantum-chemistry

I am reading Szabo - 1967 - Modern Quantum Chemistry. In Chapter 3 P122, it mentions that the spin orbitals $\left|\chi_a\right\rangle$ obtained by the Fock operator
$f\left|\chi_a\right\rangle=\varepsilon_a\left|\chi_a\right\rangle$ can have the symmetry of the molecule. (form a basis for an irreducible representation of the point group of the molecule)

It confuses me a lot because it is not obvious. I guess it could be done by proving $[f,P_R]=0$ (R is any element of the molecular point group). However Fock operator is not a linear operator and has a really complicated form by

$$f(1)=h(1)+\sum_b \int d \mathbf{x}_2 \chi_b^*(2) r_{12}^{-1}\left(1-\mathscr{P}_{12}\right) \chi_b(2)$$

where $h(1)=h(\mathbf x_1)$ and I do know it commutes with $P_R$, ${P}_{12}$ is exchange label 1<-->2. I don't know how to do it next.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an important question. What you need to realize is that the symmetry of the HF orbitals $\{\phi_p\}$ and the Fockian $\hat{F}$ are not guarenteed properties of the model $-$ we actually *make* $\{\phi_p\}$ and $\hat{F}$ obey certain symmetries for computational and interpretational convenience. The correct symmetries of $\{\phi_p\}$ and $\hat{F}$ depend on each other, as will be shown below.

To keep things simple, I will talk about closed shell systems only (that is, all orbitals belonging to certain irreducible representations are doubly populated); the exact wave function is then a singlet spin eigenfunction ($S=0$), and belongs to the totally symmetric irreducible representation of point group $G$.

If you did not care that much about the wave function, you could do HF calculations without imposing any kind of symmetry restraints on the orbitals! This approach is called Unrestricted HF (UHF), and can often lead to lower energies compared to a properly symmetry-adapted HF calculation, since you solve a less constrained optimization problem, as discussed in Chapter 3.8 of Szabo & Ostlund. Their UHF spin orbitals for H$_2$
$$
|\psi\rangle=\cos(\theta)|\sigma^+_g\rangle+\sin(\theta)|\sigma^+_u\rangle 
\ \ \ , \ \ \
|\bar{\psi}\rangle=\cos(\theta)|\bar{\sigma}^+_g\rangle-\sin(\theta)|\bar{\sigma}^+_u\rangle
$$
break both spin and spatial symmetry for $\theta\neq0$, and neither the UHF determinant, nor $\hat{F}$ have the correct $^1\Sigma_g^+$ symmetry.

This example shows that point group symmetry is not cemented in the HF formalism, but we have to enforce it. One way to do this would be the projection of the UHF Ansatz onto the subspace of the desired symmetry: $$
|\Psi\rangle=\hat{P}_S\hat{P}_G|\Phi_{\text{UHF}}\rangle \ ,
$$
which, however has its own problems (appearance of non-differentiable points on potential energy curves, violation of size consistency, etc.).
A much better way to ensure the global symmetry is to force the set of HF orbitals to be symmetry orbitals (forming the basis of the irreducible representations of $G$). In LCAO calculations for molecules, this is achieved by taking the appropriate symmetry-adapted linear combinations of fixed atomic orbitals, while in atomic calculations ($G=O(3)$), we write the orbitals in the form
$$
\phi_{nlm}(r,\Omega)=\chi_{nl}(r)Y^m_l(\Omega) \ ,
$$
and solve the HF equations for the radial parts.

This is where we can actually turn to your question about the symmetry of the Fockian. If $\hat{F}$ (built from symmetry orbitals) was not totally symmetric under the action of $G$, then the orbitals could not have been made symmetry orbitals in the first place! We have to check the inner consistency of our choice; we simply have to see if $\phi_p$ and $\hat{F}\phi_p$ belong to the same symmetry species. If $\phi_p$ is the basis function of a $D$-dimensional irreducible representation of $G$, then the action of $\hat{R}\in G$ reads
$$
\hat{R}\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r})=\sum_{q=1}^DR_{pq}\phi_q(\boldsymbol{r}) \ ,
$$
where $\boldsymbol{R}$ is a unitary matrix representation of $\hat{R}$. The action of $\hat{F}$ reads
$$
\hat{F}\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r})=\hat{h}\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r})+
\int\mathrm{d}^3r'
\frac{1}{|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}'|}
\left[
\gamma(\boldsymbol{r}',\boldsymbol{r}')\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r})
-\frac{1}{2}\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r}') 
\right] \ ,
$$
$\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')$ denoting the one-body reduced density matrix:
$$
\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')=
2\sum_{k\in \, \text{occ}}
\phi^{*}_k(\boldsymbol{r}')\phi_k(\boldsymbol{r}) \ .
$$
The two terms of $\hat{F}\phi_p$ correspond to the direct (Coulomb) and exchange interactions, respectively (the factor of 2 stemming from the spin summation).
Operators $\hat{h}$ and $1/|\boldsymbol{r}_1-\boldsymbol{r}_2|$ are totally symmetric under $G$ (pretty much by construction), so the action of $\hat{R}$
on $\hat{F}\phi_p$ looks like
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{R}\hat{F}\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r})
&=
\hat{h}\hat{R}\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r})+
\int\mathrm{d}^3r'
\frac{1}{|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}'|}\hat{R}
\left[
2\gamma(\boldsymbol{r}',\boldsymbol{r}')\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r})
-\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r}') 
\right] \\
&=
\hat{h}\hat{R}\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r})+
\int\mathrm{d}^3r'
\frac{1}{|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}'|}
\left[
2[\hat{R}\gamma(\boldsymbol{r}',\boldsymbol{r}')]\hat{R}\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r})
-[\hat{R}\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')]\hat{R}\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r}') 
\right] \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
To see the effect of $\hat{R}$ on $\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')$,
we split the $k$-sum between the $\cal{N}$ irreducible representations the orbitals occupy (for e.g. a Ne atom, the sum runs over two one-dimensional and a three-dimensional representation corresponding to $1s$, $2s$ and $2p$):
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{R}\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')
&=
2\hat{R}\sum_{a=1}^{\cal{N}}\sum_{d=1}^{D_a}
\phi^{*}_{ad}(\boldsymbol{r}')\phi_{ad}(\boldsymbol{r}) \\
&=
2\sum_{a=1}^{\cal{N}}\sum_{d=1}^{D_a}
\sum_{d_1,d_2=1}^{D_a}
R^{(a)*}_{dd_1}R^{(a)}_{dd_2}
\phi^{*}_{ad_1}(\boldsymbol{r}')\phi_{ad_2}(\boldsymbol{r}) \\
&=
2\sum_{a=1}^{\cal{N}}\sum_{d_1,d_2=1}^{D_a}
\delta_{d_1d_2}
\phi^{*}_{ad_1}(\boldsymbol{r}')\phi_{ad_2}(\boldsymbol{r}) \\
&=
2\sum_{a=1}^{\cal{N}}\sum_{d_1=1}^{D_a}
\phi^{*}_{ad_1}(\boldsymbol{r}')\phi_{ad_1}(\boldsymbol{r}) \\
&=
\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}') \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where the unitarity of $\boldsymbol{R}$ was used. So $\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')$ is symmetric under $G$, and then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{R}\hat{F}\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r})
&=
\hat{h}\hat{R}\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r})+
\int\mathrm{d}^3r'
\frac{1}{|\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{r}'|}
\left[
2\gamma(\boldsymbol{r}',\boldsymbol{r}')\hat{R}\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r})
-\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')\hat{R}\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r}') 
\right] \\
&=
\hat{F}\hat{R}\phi_p(\boldsymbol{r}) \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
explicitly showing the correct symmetry of $\hat{F}$.
But if $\hat{F}$ is totally symmetric, then its eigenfunctions can be chosen to be symmetry functions, and thus we have come full circle.

So, the main message is: $\hat{F}$ is not necessarily totally symmetric under $G$, but it can be made symmetric with the proper parametrization of orbitals in a perfectly consistent way.

Note, however, that the above considerations are generally only true for closed-shell systems. If some of the orbitals in a given irreducible representation are only partially filled, then the product of the unitary matrices cannot be completed, hence $\hat{R}\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')\neq\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')$ in general, and $\hat{F}$ is not totally symmetric. For example, the HF potential typically does not have spherical symmetry for open-shell atoms.

**An extra detail**

It might be useful to know that for closed shell atoms, the $O(3)$ invariance of $\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')$ immediately follows from the addition theorem of spherical harmonics as well:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\gamma(\boldsymbol{r},\boldsymbol{r}')
&=
\sum_{n,l}
 \chi_{nl}(r)\chi_{nl}(r')
\sum_{m=-l}^{+l}Y_l^m(\Omega)Y_l^{m*}(\Omega') \\
&=
\sum_{n,l}
 \chi_{nl}(r)\chi_{nl}(r')
\frac{2l+1}{4\pi}P_l(\cos(\alpha)) \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The final result depends only on $r$, $r'$ and $\alpha$ (the angle enclosed by $\boldsymbol{r}$ and $\boldsymbol{r}'$), making the rotational symmetry manifest.

**Update (2023.08.13.)**

All the derivations above were carried out in coordinate representation. While this representation is more intuitive, the action of the symmetry operators on different coordinates is not always clear enough. For this reason, I will now redo the derivations in a representation-free fashion.

Let us have two Hilbert spaces $H_1$ and $H_2$ each having the same set of symmetry adapted orbitals $|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle\in H_1$, $|\phi_p^{(2)}\rangle\in H_2$. The action of the Fockian on say $|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle$ then reads
$$
\hat{F}|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle=\hat{h}|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle+
\sum_{k \in \, \text{occ}}
\left[2\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_k^{(2)}\rangle|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle-\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_p^{(2)}\rangle|\phi_k^{(1)}\rangle\right] \ ,
$$
where $\hat{V}$ is the electron-electron interaction operator acting on $H_1\otimes H_2$. Note that $\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_k^{(2)}\rangle$ and $\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_p^{(2)}\rangle$ are not numbers but one-body operators acting on $H_1$. As a sanity check, you may verify that the above equation turns into the coordinate-representation version (given above) after projecting with $\langle\boldsymbol{r}_1|$, inserting
$$
1=\int\mathrm{d}^3r'_1|\boldsymbol{r}'_1\rangle\langle\boldsymbol{r}'_1| \ \ \ , \ \ \
1=\int\mathrm{d}^3r''_2|\boldsymbol{r}''_2\rangle\langle\boldsymbol{r}''_2| \ ,
$$
and using
$$
\langle\boldsymbol{r}_1|\hat{h}|\boldsymbol{r}'_1\rangle=
\hat{h}(\boldsymbol{r}_1)\delta(\boldsymbol{r}_1-\boldsymbol{r}'_1)
\ \ \ , \ \ \ 
\langle\boldsymbol{r}_1\boldsymbol{r}_2|\hat{V}|\boldsymbol{r}'_1\boldsymbol{r}'_2\rangle=
\frac{1}{|\boldsymbol{r}_1-\boldsymbol{r}_2|}
\delta(\boldsymbol{r}_1-\boldsymbol{r}'_1)\delta(\boldsymbol{r}_2-\boldsymbol{r}'_2) \ .
$$
The symmetry operator $\hat{R}_1$ acts on $|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle$ as
$$
\hat{R}_1|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle=\sum_{q=1}^DR_{pq}|\phi_q^{(1)}\rangle \ ,
$$
and the analogous equation holds for $\hat{R}_2$ and $|\phi_p^{(2)}\rangle$ (note that the $R_{pq}$ matrix elements do not carry any Hilbert space index).
Now, let us hit $\hat{F}|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle$ with $\hat{R}_1$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{R}_1\hat{F}|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle
&=
\hat{R}_1\hat{h}|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle
+
\sum_{k \in \, \text{occ}}
\left[2\hat{R}_1\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_k^{(2)}\rangle|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle-\hat{R}_1\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_p^{(2)}\rangle|\phi_k^{(1)}\rangle\right] \\
&=
\hat{h}\hat{R}_1|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle
+
\sum_{k \in \, \text{occ}}
\left[2\hat{R}_1\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_k^{(2)}\rangle\hat{R}_1^{\dagger}\hat{R}_1|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle-\hat{R}_1\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_p^{(2)}\rangle\hat{R}_1^{\dagger}\hat{R}_1|\phi_k^{(1)}\rangle\right] \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We used $\hat{R}_1^{\dagger}\hat{R}_1=\hat{I}_1$ and
$\hat{R}_1^{\dagger}\hat{h}\hat{R}_1=\hat{h}$. We need to work out the transformation of the two remaining terms. The direct part reads
$$
\begin{aligned}
\sum_{k \in \, \text{occ}}
\hat{R}_1\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_k^{(2)}\rangle\hat{R}_1^{\dagger}
&=
\sum_{k \in \, \text{occ}}
\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{R}_1\hat{V}\hat{R}_1^{\dagger}|\phi_k^{(2)}\rangle \\
&=
\sum_{k \in \, \text{occ}}
\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{R}_2^{\dagger}\hat{R}_2\hat{R}_1\hat{V}\hat{R}_1^{\dagger}\hat{R}_2^{\dagger}\hat{R}_2|\phi_k^{(2)}\rangle \\
&=
\sum_{k \in \, \text{occ}}
\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{R}_2^{\dagger}\hat{V}\hat{R}_2|\phi_k^{(2)}\rangle \\
&=
\sum_{a=1}^{\cal{N}}
\sum_{d=1}^{D_a}
\langle\phi_{ad}^{(2)}|\hat{R}_2^{\dagger}\hat{V}\hat{R}_2|\phi_{ad}^{(2)}\rangle \\
&=
\sum_{a=1}^{\cal{N}}
\sum_{d=1}^{D_a}
\sum_{d_1,d_2=1}^{D_a}
R_{dd_1}^{(a)*}R_{dd_2}^{(a)}
\langle\phi_{ad_1}^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_{ad_2}^{(2)}\rangle \\
&=
\sum_{a=1}^{\cal{N}}
\sum_{d_1=1}^{D_a}
\langle\phi_{ad_1}^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_{ad_1}^{(2)}\rangle \\
&=
\sum_{k \in \, \text{occ}}
\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_k^{(2)}\rangle \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
We used $\hat{R}_1\hat{R}_2=\hat{R}_2\hat{R}_1$ and $(\hat{R}_1\hat{R}_2)\hat{V}(\hat{R}_1\hat{R}_2)^{\dagger}=\hat{V}$.
This means that
$$
\sum_{k \in \, \text{occ}}
\hat{R}_1\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_k^{(2)}\rangle\hat{R}_1^{\dagger}\hat{R}_1|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle=
\sum_{k \in \, \text{occ}}
\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_k^{(2)}\rangle\hat{R}_1|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle \ .
$$
As for the exchange term, you can verify
$$
\sum_{k \in \, \text{occ}}
\hat{R}_1\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_p^{(2)}\rangle\hat{R}_1^{\dagger}\hat{R}_1|\phi_k^{(1)}\rangle=
\sum_{k \in \, \text{occ}}
\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}\hat{R}_2|\phi_p^{(2)}\rangle|\phi_k^{(1)}\rangle
$$
in a similar manner. Now, remember that the Hilbert space indices are only for bookkeeping which operators act on which states, so we can finally write
$$
\begin{aligned}
\hat{R}_1\hat{F}|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle
&=
\hat{h}\hat{R}_1|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle
+
\sum_{k \in \, \text{occ}}
\left[2\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}|\phi_k^{(2)}\rangle\hat{R}_1|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle-
\langle\phi_k^{(2)}|\hat{V}\hat{R}_2|\phi_p^{(2)}\rangle|\phi_k^{(1)}\rangle
\right] \\
&=
\hat{F}\hat{R}_1|\phi_p^{(1)}\rangle \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
or just (leaving the now unnecessary indices)
$$
\hat{R}\hat{F}|\phi_p\rangle=\hat{F}\hat{R}|\phi_p\rangle \ .
$$

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your gorgeous answers. Recently I revisit this answer and I find two things that puzzle me. 1)Why can operator R go into the integral without changing the (dr)? 2) why is Rf(r)f(r')= Rf(r) Rf(r')?

Comment: @Zharip Thanks for the feedback. I have updated my answer, let me know if something's not clear.